# A verb to describe the development of a wish

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am a non-native speaker.

Consider a couple whose wish to have children only recently has ...

Well, what?
What verb should I use to describe the development of a wish?

`developed` sounds to formal in my opinion.

I could think of `emerged`, too, but it just doesn't sound right as well.

A phrase would be fine, too. This is needed for a work of fiction.

Comment: ". . . has only recently *arisen*."

Comment: @Robusto thank you. On a side note, would the clause position you just proposed (*has only recently* instead of *only recently has*) be more correct?

Comment: Either will do. The way I gave it sounds better to my ear, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Wishes "come to fruition," or "manifest."

Comment: "come to fruition"means to happen as intended, which is why it's used for wishes.  "Manifest" means to make real.  The definition for "arisen" that means "to become real" is the 6th definition.  Most people use the word to mean rise from a chair or get up.  It will sound odd if used.

Comment: "... has only recently *formed*."

Comment: So are you saying that the wish didn't exist before, but now it does—but it is not yet realized (fulfilled)? That is, the wished-for thing or event has not arrived?

Comment: It is definitely fiction if "their" wish to have children arose _concurrently_ Anyway, this is how it is more likely to  play out  in real life:  She wishes to have a baby. She subtly makes hints to him that she wishes to have a baby. He either doesn't catch the hints, or dismisses them as foolish. She makes stronger hints that _he should wish_ for a baby. He ignores these hints as well.  She _needs_ to have a baby. She "accidentally forgets" to take her birth-control pills.  She announces she's pregnant. Now he gets the hint and says, "Oh, Dear, isn't that wonderful!" or just "Oh dear!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I think you left out the part where he actually gets the hint and starts using condoms to his wife surprise, who will, in turn, ask where got a STD. I think you also failed to point out that after that, he, enraged, will admit to have slept with a trans-gender prositute from Thailand at least once a week. The following divorce and the former husband's sex reversal followed by him starting a new life as a now female sex slave for a thai businessman are mandatory. But I still don't know how this supposed to help me with my question.

Comment: Clearly, you have a great imagination—an excellent trait for a fiction writer!

Comment: 1. There is nothing particularly formal about *developed* here. 2. You are not clear about whether you want to stress the evolution/development from an incipient desire or its birth/coming into being from nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **"surfaced"**.

> - "a couple whose wish to have children has only recently surfaced."

"surface", an intransitive verb in your sentence.

> - to appear or become obvious after being hidden or not seen. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surface)

e.g.

"The information **surfaced** many years later."

"As new information **surfaced**, the police had to change their strategy."

"She tried to bottle up her hatred. It worked for a few years but then all those feelings **surfaced** within her."